# Enforce database constraint

Tags: database-design

Below are database excerpt in question. What I need is to enforce that `ParamInstance` cannot be linked to `DomainParam` from different DomainType then `DomainInstance` to which this `ParameterInstance` belongs to. How this can be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)  Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS What do you think this has to do with [tag:database-normalization]? The word doesn't mean "good design".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column to `ParamInstance` called `domainType`.

Then replace the foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE ParamInstance
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (member, domainType) REFERENCES DomainParam (id, domain),
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (dmoain, domainType) REFERENCES DomainInstance (id, type);
```

You'll have to create new UNIQUE KEYs in those referenced tables first:

```
ALTER TABLE DomainParam ADD UNIQUE KEY (id, domain);

ALTER TABLE DomainInstance ADD UNIQUE KEY (id, type);
```